# iTunes integration advice

Tags: windows, itunes

I'd like to get some feedback and references to any useful resources related to iTunes integration on Windows platform from fellow developers experienced in that area. COM SDK vs. JavaScript API? What are the advantages and limitations? Any useful blogs or discussion groups? Any recommended outsourced vendors experienced in this type of work? What would be involved in developing an application with features similar to simplifymedia.com?

Any information on the topic is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I built a WebForms app in ASP.NET on my workstation using the COM SDK. It was extremely easy and I would recommend using the COM SDK for compiled code or VBScripting.

I would use a JavaScript API if you're doing a simple web app or sidebar gadget or something like that.

The APIs are defined for different domains.

And from my experience with the COM SDK, using it was extremely simple and easy, but I was just doing something simple.